# Implementing a simple greedy ai for reversi/othello

Tags: haskell

Quick disclaimer that this is for a homework task so rather than me placing any code I wanted to get conceptual help from you guys, maybe examples to help me understand. Essentially we have to implement an ai for reversi/othello and while minmax is the final goal, I wanted to start with a greedy algorithm.

Ok so the relevant definitions/functions:

**GameState** - this variable holds the boundaries of the board, who's turn it is, and the board (with a list of Maybe Player where Nothing means the tile is empty and Maybe Player1 or Player2 which means a piece is present for a player.

**legalMoves** - returns a list of all possible legal moves when given a GameState. Here a move is defined as a position (x,y)

**applyMove** - finally we have applyMove which takes a GameState and a move and returns a new Maybe GameState based on the new board after that move was played.

The final goal here is to create a function that when given a GameState, returns the best move

What I've done:
Firstly, I've created an evaluation function which returns the eval of any GameState
(eval :: GameState -> Int). So a heuristic.

From here I've had trouble. What I've tried to do is map the applyMove func to legalMoves to return a list of all possible future GameStates given a GameState. Then I mapped my eval func to the list of GameStates to get a list of Int's then I finally took the maximum of this list to get the best evaluation.
**The problem is I'm not sure how to go back to the actual move from legalMoves that gave me that evaluation.**

Comment: Store the actual move with each Legal Move.

Comment: Actually, you should already have this.  If legalMoves is storing references (which I suspect it is), you already have references to the original moves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current pipeline looks like this:

```
GameState -> (GameState, [Move]) -> [GameState] -> [Int] -> Int
```

Make it look like this instead:

```
GameState -> (GameState, [Move]) -> [(Move, GameState)] -> [(Move, Int)] -> (Move, Int)
```

In other words: track the association between moves and function return values through the whole pipeline. Then it is easy to extract the `Move` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a 10-liners with a MiniMax strategy: https://github.com/haskell-game/tiny-games-hs/blob/main/prelude/mini-othello/mini-othello.hs

The key is to use the trial play function:

```hs
-- | Trial play
(%) :: GameState -> Coordinate -> (GameState, Int)
(%) inGameState -> cor -> (outGameState, nFlips)
```

To create different game strategy function `e`:

```hs
-- | Strategy function!
e :: GameState -> GameState
This generates a sequence of [(nFlips, (x,y)), ...]
((,)=<<snd.(a%))&k r
-- | Naive strategy
e a=q a.snd.head.f((>0).fst).m((,)=<<snd.(a%)$k r
-------------------------------------------------
-- | Greedy strategy
e a=q a.snd.f(\c@(w,_)e@(d,_)->d>w?e$c)(0,(0,0)).m((,)=<<snd.(a%))$k r
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- | MiniMax strategy
i=fst;j=snd;
g h a=f(\c e->i e>i c?e$c)(-65*h,(0,0))$
        (\((b,p),d)->(h*(h*p==0?j a`c`i b$i$g(div h(-2))b),d))&
        (((,)=<<(a%))&k r);
e a=q a.j$g 4a
```

Because is a code golfing exercise, many symbols are involved here:

```
? a b c -- if' operator
& = map
```